# Unable to provide CLI arguments to `cargo test`

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo, structopt

I used to be able to run specific, named tests from the command-line interface like this: `cargo test <test_name>`. But now this gives me the error

```
running 1 test
error: Found argument '<test_name>' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

Other arguments to `cargo test` also don't work.

The line that causes the error is this line in the test setup:

```rust
let cli_default_args = Arc::new(cli_args::Args::from_args());
```

Where the `cli_args::Args` struct is a struct that holds the value of the command line arguments and the `from_args` function comes from the `StructOpt` package derivation. `cli_args::Args` is decorated with `#[derive(StructOpt)]`.

Comment: May be related: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/cargo-test-nocapture-no-longer-works/65144/9

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that arguments intended for `cargo test` were interpreted as arguments for the application.

Replacing the problematic line in the test setup

```rust
let cli_default_args = Arc::new(cli_args::Args::from_args());
```

with

```rust
let cli_default_args = Arc::new(cli_args::Args::from_iter::<Vec<String>>(vec![]));
```

fixes the problem. The above code means that your test setup runs as if the program didn't get any CLI arguments, everything is running with its default values.